# Best practice- when return in JS function

Tags: javascript

it happened to me multiple times that I face situation where I wasnt sure how I should stop function when I know result.

Just for example lets imagine we have object category which looks like:

```
{
    "name": "CategoryName",
    "subCategoriess": [{
        "name": "Sub1",
        "value": true
    }, {
        "name": "Sub2",
        "value": false
    }]
}
```

and we want to iterate over it until we found `value === true`

Clasic option (let's call it: **Option 1**)which i found in most documentation is:

```
function myFunction(category){
  var ret = false;
  for (var i=0; i <category.subCategoriess.length; i++)
  {
    ret = category.subCategories[i].value;
    if (ret)
      break;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I alternativly saw something like this (let's call it: **Option 2**):

```
   function myFunction(category){
      for (var i=0; i <category.subCategoriess.length; i++)
      {
        if (category.subCategories[i].value) return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

So let's compare this two options, i consider my self as junior so I may be wrong really easy so please do not hesitate to tell me that

- **Option 1** - Advantage of this option is that even if your code is more complicated you always know which return actualy "return" the function and I expect it may be easier for debug for many of us.
- **Option 2** - Advantage of this option is that it should use less performance becuase it doesnt need aditional variabile (`ret`) + we basicly avoid atleast one step where we break a `for` loop and going to actual `return` statment

In this particular example the differenc between each option is something really close to 0.  But code can get more complicated so may I ask you guys **what option is best practice** (or if I miss something please add your option) and why it should be used like this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having more than one `return` statement.

Comment: Whatever is more readable and comprehensible in the given context. There is no one strict rule or template to follow; you write it the way it fits best to solve the given problem.

Comment: I think this is more of a style question. A lot depends on who is reading the code. Some find option 2 easier to comprehend while others may find option 2 easier. When working on your own personal projects you have the opportunity to choose which style best suits you. Sometimes maybe choose the common one found in other popular projects. Other times pick which fells best for you. The key is to remain consistent within a project. My personal styles have changed several times over the years.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233410/python-only-one-return-per-method, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/198587/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-temporary-variables-vs-multiple-returns ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more then just two options and it comes down to this:

> Which do you (or your team) find is more comprehensible with the lowest cognitive load to read?

Some find procedural code easier. Some attempt to lower temp variables by returning early. Still some find a functional approach better:

```
return subject.collection.some(function (item) {
  return !!item.value;
});
```

So it comes down to your team and your own cognitive preferences. The true take away is be consistent in your project. If you start with one style and find you like a new style note this in the README and maybe convert old styles as you see them.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer to this question is: **it depends** (on code complexity)

Generally speaking, multiple return statement could make debugging a bit harder, but sometimes it is worth it.

In your example I'd probably go for the second option if I'd be sure that this method would only return true/false value.
But if I'd like to extend it's functionality in the future (fetch the record which fulfills the condition or get all the values that fulfill it) it may be easier to go for the first option.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say option 2 because you don't need any intermediary variable to store the result, and the intent is clearer since you return immediately as soon as you can.

You can also improve legibility and performance (a bit) by storing each item as you iterate.

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = category.subCategoriess[i]; i++) {
  if (item.value) return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score -4):

How about **Option 3**?

Using `Array.some` gives you the best of both worlds as it doesn't require a `break` or multiple `return` statements.

```js
var category = {
    "name": "CategoryName",
    "subCategoriess": [{
        "name": "Sub1",
        "value": true
    }, {
        "name": "Sub2",
        "value": false
    }]
}

function myFunction(category){
  var result = category.subCategoriess.some(function(subCategory) {
    return subCategory.value;
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(myFunction(category))
```

Comment: This isn't really addressing the question, which is off topic anyway, and the variable is really just unnecessary at that position.